# EKS POD terminated immediately after running

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am beginner at Kubernetes and EKS. I am trying to run a cluster on AWS using EKS and Terraform. The cluster is created, the image is pulled on the worker node successfully and status of the POD changes from creating container to 'running' but **immediately** it changes to failed and 'Terminated'.
I described the POD but have not found any useful information. The error message is:

[image]

which is not very helpful for me. I would appreciate your help.
/thanks

Comment: Is there anything in the logs from the pod?

Comment: @Jonas I can see this: Conditions:
  Type:Status,Initialized:True,   Ready: False, ContainersReady: False, PodScheduled:True.  Also this:                                                                   
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s and at the end is the event log but it says: successfully pulled the image, created container and started the container and no more event after that.

Comment: Do you have a livenessProbe defined for the pod?

Comment: @Jonas No I don't know how to do that. I am beginner at this.

Comment: Please don't use images to post code snippets; it's explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You'll also want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63876222/edit) and include `kubectl logs $your_pod_name` as Jonas originally requested

Comment: sure, I wont use it  anymore, I tried to get the log but log is destroyed immediately so I cannot take log

Comment: @shahab4ai have you tried to pass `--previous` to your `$ kubectl logs command`? Have you by any chance tried to run your image outside of `EKS`?